How to get inheritance like features with costructor defined on "parent"?
I try to have something in Rust like a struct SomeStruct<T> that does most of the heavy lifting in a generic way and also implements a generic constructor, but there are some small variations depending on the type T. In other languages, I would simply implement this with a parent class that contains most of the code and inherit subtypes from it, e.g. in Python:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class SomeStruct(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_value = 1

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
        
    def bar(self):
        return self.some_value + self.foo()
    
class A(SomeStruct):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

class B(SomeStruct):
    def foo(self):
        return 2
    
class C(SomeStruct):
    def foo(self):
        return 3
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    c = C()
    print(a.bar() + b.bar() + c.bar())

What I tried in Rust is using empty Enums as subtypes:
trait SomeType {
    fn new() -> SomeStruct<Self> where Self: Sized {
        SomeStruct {
            struct_type: Self,
            some_value: 1,
        }
    }

    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}

struct SomeStruct<T> {
    struct_type: T,
    some_value: i32,
}

enum A {}
impl SomeType for A {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 1 }
}

enum B {}
impl SomeType for B {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 2 }
}

enum C {}
impl SomeType for C {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 3 }
}

impl<T> SomeStruct<T> {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 where T: SomeType {
        self.some_value + self.struct_type.foo()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new();
    let b = B::new();
    let c = C::new();
    println!("{}", a.bar() + b.bar() + c.bar());
}

However, this does not compile because assigning a type to a variable in line 4, struct_type: Self, is not allowed.
Is there a way to fix this and get a similar behavior without needing to re-implement the construtor for each of A, B, C?
I found this related question, which I guess I could make work for my case, replacing A, B, C with structs that contain a parent struct SomeStruct, but I was curious if there might also be a way to make the empty enum solution work, or if I'm just on the completely wrong track with that?

The most direct equivalence will be to have a trait with method for each customization with default implementations. But depending on your constraints, this might not be the most Rusty solution.

This is the most straightforward way to make your code work: remove struct_type and replace it with a PhantomData, and remove the &self arg from SomeType::foo: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f1761ac3ffb2af99a93efa367c490f1 However, this is not very idiomatic Rust. Your question is probably an XY problem.

I realize that it may be solely for the purposes of a MRE that you are using sequential integers but in this case I think it actually detracts from the question: because foo at least as it's written now is the kind of thing one doesn't generally need to write in a language with proper sum types like Rust has. What are the actual differences between the variants?

A, B and C don't need to be enums, they can just as well be zero sized structs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed69acc8e30225af4c85f8e14eeec859

Thanks everyone! I learned a lot from your comments and my troubleshooting attempts :). The zero sized structs were, what I ended up using in the end and finally got a working solution for my use case.
The main problem was that I have my generic type SomeType has a whole bunch of implementations (e.g. Add, Sub, ...) that are the same for all T, but I had a derived type that needed to contain a Vec<SomeType>.
To get new instances with T::new(), I used a SomeStruct::new(struct_type) and then implemented a one line new() method for each subtype.

Here is a solution which takes an inverted approach from the one presented in the question:
trait SomeType {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}

struct SomeStruct<T> {
    some_type_field: T,
    some_value: i32,
}

impl<T> SomeStruct<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> SomeStruct<T> {
        SomeStruct {
            some_type_field: t,
            some_value: 1,
        }
    }
    
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 where T: SomeType {
        self.some_value + self.some_type_field.foo()
    }
}

struct A;
impl SomeType for A {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 1 }
}

struct B;
impl SomeType for B {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 2 }
}

struct C;
impl SomeType for C {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 3 }
}

fn main() {
    let a = SomeStruct::new(A);
    let b = SomeStruct::new(B);
    let c = SomeStruct::new(C);
    println!("{}", a.bar() + b.bar() + c.bar());
}

Instead of relying on inheritance, the core of the logic stays in the concrete SomeStruct type.
It makes use of composition in order to wrap the common logic around instances of A, B, and C.
While it is mostly a matter of personal preference, I usually don't rely on complex constructors or inheritance in Rust, as I found these Object-Oriented patterns don't map well to the language's philosophy.
Playground link
